# Reduced Row Echelon Form for an augmented matrix in library SymPy of Python

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

When running the following code

```
from sympy import *
A,B = symbols("A B ")
A = Matrix([[2,-1,1,3],[3,1,-2,-2],[1,-1,1,7],[1,5,7,13],[1,-7,-5,12]])
B = A.rref(pivots=False) 
B
```

i get:

[image]

I wanted:

[image]

Is there a function?

Comment: You don't need 5 rows here. Just take 3 out of 5 then form a 3x4 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Just take 3 rows out of 5 and then form a 3x4 matrix.

By choosing first 3 rows,

```py
Matrix([[2,-1,1,3],[3,1,-2,-2],[1,-1,1,7]]).rref(pivots=False)
```

Result

```
⎡1  0  0  -4 ⎤
⎢            ⎥
⎢0  1  0  -32⎥
⎢            ⎥
⎣0  0  1  -21⎦
```

Thank you!